# For loop prints twie

Tags: for-loop

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int o;

int menu;
printf("\n\t\t\t\t _________________________________________\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|                CONVERTER                |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|=========================================|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    1    |    Decimal    to     Binary   |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    2    |    Binary     to     Decimal  |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    3    |    Octal      to     Binary   |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    4    |    Octal      to     Decimal  |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    5    |    Decimal    to     Octal    |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    6    |    Hexa       to     Decimal  |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|         |                               |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|    0    |    Quit                       |\n");
printf("\t\t\t\t|_________|_______________________________|\n");
printf("\n");

for(o=1;o<=50;o++){
printf("\n\t\t\t\t              Please select\n\n\t\t\t\t                    ");
menu = getchar();

    switch (menu)
    {
        case '1':{
            long int decimalNumber,quotient;
            int binaryNumber[100],i=1,j;
            printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter any decimal number: ");
            scanf("%ld",&decimalNumber);
            printf("\n");

            quotient = decimalNumber;


            while(quotient!=0){

                binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;

                quotient = quotient / 2;}


printf("\t\t\t\tEquivalent binary value is: ");

for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--){

     printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);
}
printf("\n");
// o+= o + 1;
   }
            break;


        case '2':{
            long int binary1;
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter any Binary Number:\n\n\t\t\t\t");
            scanf("%ld",&binary1);
            printf("\n\t\t\t\tEquivalent binary value is: ");
            int decimal=0;
            int i=0;
            int rem;
            while(binary1!=0)
            {
                rem = binary1%10;
                binary1/=10;
                decimal += rem*pow(2,i);
                ++i;
            }

            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t%d\n", decimal);
        }
            break;


        case '3':{
            long int octal1;
printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter any Octal number: ");
scanf("%ld", &octal1);
int decimal=0, binary=0, i=0;
printf("\n\t\t\t\tThe Equivalent Binary Value is: ");
while(octal1!=0)
{
    decimal+=(octal1%10)*pow(8,i);
    ++i;
    octal1/=10;
}
i=1;
while(decimal!=0)
{
    binary+=(decimal%2)*i;
    decimal/=2;
    i*=10;
}
printf("%d\n", binary);
        }
            break;


        case '4':{
                      long int octal2;
printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter any Octal number: ");
scanf("%ld", &octal2);
int decimal2=0, i=0;
printf("\n\t\t\t\tThe Equivalent Decimal Value is: ");
while(octal2!=0)
{
    decimal2+=(octal2%10)*pow(8,i);
    ++i;
    octal2/=10;
}
        printf("%d\n", decimal2);
       }
            break;


        case '5':{
       long int decimal2,quotient2;
      printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter any decimal number: ");

        scanf("%ld",&decimal2);
        int octal3[100],w=1,e;

        quotient2 = decimal2;
        while(quotient2!=0){


        octal3[w++]= quotient2%8;

        quotient2 = quotient2 / 8;

}
        printf("\n\t\t\t\tEquivalent octal value is: ");
        for(e=w-1;e>0;e--)
        printf("%d", octal3[e]);
        printf("\n");

        }
            break;


        case '6':{
            unsigned int q;
            printf("\n\t\t\t\tEnter any Hexadecimal number: ");
            scanf("%x", &q);
            printf("\nThe Equivalent decimal value is: ");
            printf("%d\n", q);
        }
            break;


        case '0':{

            printf("\n\t\t\t\t              Are you sure?\n\n\t\t\t\t              y or n: ");
            char b[9];
            scanf("%s", b);
            if(strcmp(b,"y")==0){
            o=o+50;
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t              Have a nice day!\n\n");}

            }

            break;

    }



    }


    return 0;

}
```

After getting the result for an item in the menu, the "Please select" phrase prints 2 times before letting you select another menu item.

Why is it printing 2 times?

This is a converter program as a project for my basic programming subject. We were told to make a program that converts these numbers, and after converting a number, the program should not end and should let you select another option or select the "quit" for exiting the program.

Comment: Are there any particular reason why you're using for-loop to re-display the selection screen instead of a do-while loop? You're manually assigning the value of variable "o" which is not good practice.. Try using a do-while loop instead and that might help get rid of the double please select issue

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. i'll try you suggestion and be back for feedback. thanks again

Comment: hello @JohnEphraimTugado, i tried a do-while but it was still the same. it displays 2 times. luckily i found a fix. here is the last part of my final code:`>printf("\n\t\tPress any key to continue. . .");
    >fflush(stdin);
    >getchar();
    >return main();
`

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and debugged it. It seems that after selecting an option and inputting the number to be converted the value of "menu = getchar();" becomes 10 and doesn't wait for any user input which the value is not handled in your switch(menu). Consider using scanf instead as this worked fine for me. Remember that you declared menu as an int and not char so I guess that must be the reason for your trouble...

Use

```
scanf("%ld", &menu);
```

And replace the case statements like this..

```
case '1': // change to case 1:
case '2': // change to case 2:
```

and so on.. since the value will be int instead of char.